# Using CAML Query to Retreive from Multiple Lists

Tags: list, caml, query

I am creating an applicant tool which contains the following lists:

Applicant; Applicant Answers; Job Questionnaire; Job Title

The lists are related as follows:

```
Applicant.ID = Applicant Answers.ApplicantID;
Applicant.JobApplicant = JobTitle.Title;
JobQuestionnaire.JobTitle = JobTitle.Title;
JobQuestionnaire.ID = Applicant Answers.QuestionID;
```

I need to load the questions and answers. I can load the answers from the Applicant Answer list, however, I cannot load the question text from there. Instead, I need to use the relationships listed above to retrieve the Question Text, which is a field in Job Questionnaire based on the Question ID.

I have done some research and noticed that I can't use one query to retrieve from two lists. What can I do in order to retrieve the Question Text?

Answer (score 2):

You can query based on relations in two lists, please have a look at [List Joins and Projections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539975(v=office.14).aspx)

You can use joins to get the projected field Question Text, something like:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();

query.Join = @"
<Joins>
  <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='Applicant Answers'>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='QuestionID' RefType='Id'/>
      <FieldRef List='JobQuestionnaire' Name='ID'/>
    </Eq>
  </Join>
</Joins>";

query.ProjectedFields = @"
<Field Name='ProjectQuestionText' Type='Text' List='JobQuestionnaire' ShowField='QuestionText'/>";

SPQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ProjectQuestionText'/>";

SPList questionList = web.Lists["JobQuestionnaire"];
SPListItemCollection items = questionList.GetItems(query);                
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    var questionText = item["ProjectQuestionText"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. But I need to use all of the relations listed above in order to get the QuestionText.
I need the Applicant ID in order to determine which applicant I'm working with. From there, I can get the Job Title, and from the Job Title I need to get the Question ID which will lead to the QuestionText. Thanks!

Comment: It is also fair to note that I'm using SharePoint 2013 - Client, not Server.

Comment: I just gave you an idea, you can add further joins.. CAML query should work on Client..

Comment: CAML does work, but the SPQuery query part does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same CAML query with the SPSiteDataQuery.  You could query on list type or supply guids to identify each list using the SPSiteDataQuery.Lists property

[how to query multiple lists using CAML](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54621/how-to-query-multiple-lists-using-caml)

```
query.Lists = "<Lists><List ID='7A9FDBE6-0841-430a-8D9A-53355801B5D5' /><List ID='3D18F506-FCA1-451e-B645-2D720DC84FD8' /></Lists>";
```

More info
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx