# Search from multiple list in caml querry

Tags: caml-query

I want to search data from multiple tables using CAML query.

Answer (score 1):

CAML doesn't support this. Instead you can look into [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx) or [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742311(v=office.14).aspx)

If the two lists are related then you can use [SPQuery.Join](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120720/using-caml-query-to-retreive-from-multiple-lists)

Comment: how using SPSiteDataQuery or LINQ it can be solved ?Can yu please provide a querry sample ? My lists are not related.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why can't you just do a caml query on each, and then abridge the results?