# How can I get two List Items using one Caml Query?

Tags: list, javascript, caml-query, item

I need to get data from two customs lists that I created. However only the first list item is queried allowing me to use the data in the Home Page list item only, but I need both.

```
var listItems;
var listItemPics;
function GetListItems(SPHostUrl){
    var SPContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(SPHostUrl);
    var web = SPContext.get_web();
    var List = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Home Page");
    var picsList = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Pictures");

    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>0</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>30</RowLimit></View>');

    listItems = List.getItems(query);
    listItemPics = picsList.getItems(query); 
    SPContext.load(listItems);
    SPContext.load(listItemPics);

    SPContext.executeQueryAsync(GetListItems_Successor, GetListItems_Fail);
}
```

GetItemsFunction

```
function GetListItems_Successor(sender, args){

    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = listItem.getEnumerator();
    var picItemEnumerator = listItemPics.getEnumerator();

    while (picItemEnumerator.moveNext()){

        var picsItem = picItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var title = picsItem.get_item('Title'); 
        var url = picsItem.get_item('URL');     } 

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()){

            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            var title = oListItem.get_item('Title');    
            var url = oListItem.get_item('URL');     }}
```

Comment: Some clarification, all the items in the "Home Page" list are queried, but no items for the "Pictures" list are queried.

Comment: Multiple examples on Google for this. One such example: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-list-joins-spquery-enchancements. This is for SSOM but should be valid for CSOM.

Comment: I don't want to join the queries together (like joining sql tables?). Unless it is the only way that I can pull data from both lists using caml query.

Comment: Show the code of GetListItems_Successor

Comment: You're not using the picItemEnumerator within the `while` statement.

Comment: Please take a look [Here](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120720/using-caml-query-to-retreive-from-multiple-lists), This will help you.

Comment: I changed it, but the problem is before the success function is called because SPContext.load(listItemPics) is null while SPContext.load(listItems) has a data object in it.

Comment: @JohnPeter in firt while you have written `var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();` I think it should be `var oListItem = picItemEnumerator .get_current();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working was the order in which the items lists were loaded. Correct code is:

```
listItems = List.getItems(query);
SPContext.load(listItems);

listItemPics = picsList.getItems(query);     
SPContext.load(listItemPics);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can load two lists by one CAML and by one `SPContext.executeQueryAsync` call. It matters how your accessing your above two lists inside `GetListItems_Successor`.

```
function GetListItems_Successor() {
    console.log(listItems.get_count());
    console.log(listItemPics.get_count());
}
```

This gave me the total items of the lists. I hope items of the lists can be also accessible inside `GetListItems_Successor`. You can load too many things in `SPContext`. just finally execute `SPContext.executeQueryAsync` once. When you are executing same CAML query on multiple lists, then make sure all lists contain same column. I was your query. It should execute on both list.

Comment: I believe that the problem is before GetListItems_Successor is called.

Comment: I run the same code as your's and it gave me results

Comment: I believe that the problem is before GetListItems function is called. In the debugger here is what is contained in the objects: 'List = SP.List {$0_0: SP.ClientContext, $2_0: SP.ClientObjectData}, camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery {$S_1: true, $R_1: "<View><Query>....."}' and 'picsList = SP.List {$0_0: SP.ClientContext, $2_0: SP.ClientObjectData}' and for SPContext.load(listItems) is 'SPContext = SP.ClientContext {$1h_0: Object, $u_0: "/sites/Technician", $1H_0: true, $2D_0: false, $1r_0: Object…}' but SP.Context.load(listItemPics) is empty, nothing shows up in the debugger.

Comment: what did you write inside GetListItems_Successor? show it in your question

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that there is not an item with an `id` of `0` in both lists like your CAML query is filtering for.

If you know the IDs of the items you want you should just use the `List.getItemById(1)` method to get individual items and avoid creating query XML manually.

If you want to make the custom query XML, I would use `SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery()` to start debugging the loading of the items.