# Using CAML Builder Is it possible to query the items from multiple list in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, caml-query, ssom, cross-list

I have three lists like List1, List2, List3. I need to retrieve an item based on conditions, Is this possible to query the items from multiple lists using Caml query builder tool [U2U](https://www.u2u.be/software). I am not sure about SiteData Query, So Please Suggest me an idea to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [SpsiteDataQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx). Also you can try to use OOTB content query web part.
From Link above

```
query.Lists = "<Lists><List ID='7A9FDBE6-0841-430a-8D9A-53355801B5D5' /><List 
ID='3D18F506-FCA1-451e-B645-2D720DC84FD8' /></Lists>";
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible using Caml query builder tool U2U.

you have to build your CAML Query as per below link :
[Using CAML Query to Retreive from Multiple Lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120720/using-caml-query-to-retreive-from-multiple-lists)